# Why are the entries in my table of contents not correctly numbered?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

[image: Output image]

```
\chapter{Introduction}\label{chapter:Introduction}
\input{chapters/Introduction}

\chapter{Literature Review}\label{chapter:Literature Review}
\input{chapters/Literature Review}

\chapter*{Proposed Methodology}\label{chapter:Proposed Methodology}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Proposed Methodology}

\input{chapters/Proposed Methodology}


\chapter*{Conclusion}\label{chapter:Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}
\input{chapters/Conclusion}
```

Comment: The Proposed Methodology was included there formatted as a chapter, but the `\chapter*{}` does not change the chapter counter. What numbering do you wish to obtain?

Comment: I see no reason for not numbering the last two chapters, particularly in view of their division into sections.

Comment: Oh i fixed it, it had something to do with \chapter*{}. I was actually using an existing thesis format and i am not very familiar with Tex coding.

Comment: If you looked at the body of your document you would  see that not every chapter was numbered. Fix that (`\chapter*` produces unnumbered chapters) and the ToC will be OK.